# Applying pure function to rotate the label in a BoxWhiskerChart

Tags: function-construction, labeling, charts, pure-function

Data is available from here

> https://www.ocr.org.uk/Images/400305-large-data-set-lds_1-h630-2018-h640-2018-2019-pre-release-data-mei.xlsx

```
dat = Import["MEI-B_LDS1.xlsx", {"Sheets", "Data"}];
```

I have replaced all `N/A` to `Missing[]`.

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{Values[#]}, ChartLegends -> Keys[#]] &@ GroupBy[dat[[2 ;;, {3, 11}]], First -> Last]
```

No problem. Works fine.
[image]

But then how to I change the labels so that they are rotated 180 degree under the axis? Like this example

[image]

Best I can do is

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{Values[#]}, ChartLabels -> Placed[Keys[#], Axis]] &@ GroupBy[dat[[2 ;;, {3, 11}]], First -> Last]
```

[image]

Struggling with the rotation due to the use of (nested?) pure functions here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the pure function `Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &` as the third argument of `Placed`:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[{Values[#]}, 
   ChartLabels -> Placed[Keys@#, Axis, Rotate[#, 90 Degree] &]] &@
 GroupBy[dat[[2 ;;, {3, 11}]], First -> Last]
```

[image]